# How did ancient people describe the Doppler effect?

Tags: acoustics, history, doppler-effect

I've noticed the Doppler effect in the change of pitch of music as I ride past on my bicycle, so I assume in the old days people did this on horses too. Are there any ancient mentions or theories about this, maybe the ancient greeks?

Comment: I think this is probably off topic here, since it's about history, not really the science itself. If so it might be a good candidate for migration to [hsm.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, cf. David Z's comment.